# passing object to a view within a foreach loop in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, for-loop, codeigniter, foreach

I'm working with CodeIgniter, passing an object to a view within a `foreach` loop. I've noticed that 'view2' prints the number '2' during the first iteration of the loop, but I can't determine why it also continues to print '2' during the second iteration.

Is this behavior due to the objects sharing memory addresses, or is it an issue with the variables used within the loop?

**Controller**

```php
function controller() {
    $result = (object) [
        (object) [ "a" => 1, "b" => 2 ],
        (object) [ "a" => 3 ]
    ];

    $this->load->view("view1", $result);
}
```

**view1**

```php
<?php 
    foreach($result as $index => $res) {
        if($index == 0) {
            $this->load->view("view2", $res);
        } else {
            $this->load->view("view2");
        }
    }

?>
```

**view2**

```php
echo $b
```

Comment: Probably because `$b` is already defined in the main view (from which view2 is loaded), so the context / scope is the same. I don't know CodeIgniter particularly but that's my asumption.

Comment: because in the second object b is not defined, so it is getting value from old instance that is 2. if you modify (object) [ "a" => 3, "b" => 3] , it will print 23

Comment: Semi-relevant: [Codeigniter : variables scope when calling a view from within a view. Odd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4029731/2943403)